# Suggestion for running ALTER migrations on large tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration, rails-migrations

We need to add a set of columns to a table that is sufficiently large (2 GB). Running a migration adding just 1 column (add_column) took 690s. Now adding 6 columns will lock the Table for almost 1 hour which is not desirable.

Any suggestions about how to get this done gracefully?
[Switching from MySQL to Postgres or any other platform is not an option.]

Comment: Can't you just set up a cron job to run it overnight then remove the cron job after it's run?

Comment: Is it about reducing possible downtime? Do you have only one DB server?

Comment: @AlmaDo Yes we only one Master DB and others are slaves. Any load or delay on Master propagates to all the slaves.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem developed by SoundCloud called Large Hadron Migrator (LHM) that simplifies these types of migrations through the use of a copy table.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can tell MySQL not to lock the table during this operation, and also use the INPLACE algorithm so the entire operation is faster.

```rb
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL.squish
      ALTER TABLE your_table
      ADD COLUMN investor_id bigint,
      ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL.squish
      ALTER TABLE your_table
      DROP COLUMN investor_id,
      ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
    SQL
  end
end
```